# PHP consume a .net service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

So i have the following web service that is found on

http://screencast.com/t/y8qM8hRDu

These are my trials and results:

**Try 1:**

```
    $api_target = "http://www.xyz.co/service1.svc?wsdl"
    $soap_options["location"] = $api_target;
    $soap_options['trace'] = TRUE;
    $soap_options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
    $soap_options['style'] = SOAP_RPC;
    $soap_options['use'] = SOAP_ENCODED;
    $soap_options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;

    $client = new SoapClient($api_target,$soap_options);
    $result = $client->Login(array("parameters" => $user));
```

**Response 1:**

```
The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/Login'.
```

**Try 2:** added SOAPaction header

```
    $actionHeader = new SoapHeader($api_target,'SOAPAction','http://tempuri.org/IService1/Login');
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);

    $client = new SoapClient($api_target,$soap_options);
    $result = $client->Login(array("parameters" => $user));
```

**Response 2:**: 
Bad Request

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

By some unexplained miracle i got it working, if it helps anyone here is the revises code

```
$api_target = "http://www.xyz.co/service1.svc";
$api_url = $api_target."?wsdl";
$action = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/Login";

$soap_options["location"] = $api_target;
$soap_options["uri"] = $api_url;
$soap_options['trace'] = TRUE;
$soap_options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
$soap_options['style'] = SOAP_DOCUMENT;
$soap_options['use'] = SOAP_LITERAL;
$soap_options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;

$actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','Action',$action , true);
$actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','To',$api_target ,true);

$client = new SoapClient($api_url,$soap_options);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);

$result = $client->__soapCall('Login',array($user));;
```